# I want to bring kibana on https.what are the ways to make it

Tags: https, kibana, kibana-4

I want to bring Kibana (opensource) on https
can any one provide me the setup or installation manual.
Any procedure or steps to setup on https

Answer (score 0):

You can read about it in the Kibana documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/production.html#enabling-ssl).

Also, read [this thread](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-https/64279) to understand what you should focus on.

Comment: Although SO requires answers to have the key points of the site that the answer is pointing to, the question is quite broad and it's impossible to contain all the information needed in the scope of the answer.